# Angular lazy loading error on child paths

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-router

So,I have right now 2 modules with in my app. Each have their own Routing module.

Only the Module components are being loaded and the rest is not.

I tried to get all the possible routes which are defined in the app and I got the following, so I know that the routes are not even being registered, But somehow I don't get an error saying the URL has not been defined.

The Output is as follows.

```
/                 create-test.component.ts:20        
/create-test      create-test.component.ts:20
/login            create-test.component.ts:20
```

My Routing files are as follows:

**CreateTestRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CreateTestComponent } from './create-test.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DesignTestComponent } from './design-test/design-test.component';
import { PlanTestComponent } from './plan-test/plan-test.component';
import { TestHistoryComponent } from './test-history/test-history.component';
import { QuestionsListComponent } from './questions-list/questions-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CreateTestComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'design-test', component: DesignTestComponent
            }, 
            {
                path: 'plan-test', component: PlanTestComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'test-history', component: TestHistoryComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'questions-list', component: QuestionsListComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],


    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CreateTestRoutingModule {

}
```

**DashboardRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SignoutComponent } from './signout/signout.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home'},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
            { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent},
            { path: 'signout', component: SignoutComponent}
        ]
    }
]



@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],


exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule{

}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guard/auth.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'create-test', loadChildren: './createtest/create-test.module#CreateTestModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My end result that i want is like this

```
/
/login
/home
/account
/signout
/create-test
/create-test/design-test
/create-test/plan-test
/create-test/test-history
/create-test/questions-list
```

**P.S**
I would like an explanation regarding why it is not throwing an error for a route that is not possible and also how I can go to `/home` but its not on the possible routes.
I don't know how the documentation has confused me. 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Only the Module components are being loaded and the rest is not.***

This is because your `AppRoutingModule` defines all the routes as lazy loaded and angular has not yet got a chance to load any of your lazy loaded modules.

**Reason**

The order of routes in your code is such that the first `''` route matches any/every url, so angular returns the 1st entry alone.

Try the below code -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create-test', loadChildren: './createtest/create-test.module#CreateTestModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

];
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that I didn't add the `<router-outlet>` tag in the html template of each of the Modules.

Thus Even though it had registered the path it was bot able to give an output.

So, if any poor souls are fighting with the same problem I suggest you to add the `<router-outlet>` tags first.